# Select item from selection box

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I want to select my country from the selection box;
http://tr.investing.com/currencies/single-currency-crosses

there is a `change_result();` in it's on change.

I get the selection box as;

```
$("#symbols")
```

But how will I trigger the on change box and reload the page according to the new selected option.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```js
    $("#myselect").change(function() {
    
         var selectedOption = $("#myselect option:selected").text();
         var selectedValue = $(this).val();
         
         // Do something here

         $("#"+selectedValue).fadeIn(1000);
    
    });
```

```html
<div id="2" style="display:none;">
Magic Text
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But the page is loading according to the selection, so alerting the text is not enough.

Comment: I wanted to give some assitance, no solution. F0r example, create hidden containers with the id of your `option values` and then fade them in

Comment: no, the page is not reloaded.. am i missing something?

Comment: No you aren't missing something. This isn't actually **the** solution, but I gave you a code to start.
Some hints: FadeOut the actual displayed container, fadeIn a loading progress bar while you're getting other datas by an ajax request

Answer (score 0):

I think this will helps you

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="symbols">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2">B</option>
  <option value="3">C</option>
</select>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#symbols').on('change',function(){
        var value=$(this).val();
        alert(value);
        });
});
</script>
```